# posting to an asp with cookies

Tags: java, asp.net, cookies, post, session-cookies

I am trying to post to an asp and get a returning page.  The page starts a session and sends me a cookie. How do I send it back in the request?

```
    URL oracle = new URL("http://taxinquiry.princegeorgescountymd.gov/taxsummary.aspx");
    HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();
    yc.setDoOutput(true);
    yc.setDoInput(true);
    yc.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
    yc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

    String cookie = yc.getHeaderField(5);

    yc.disconnect();

    HttpURLConnection yd = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();

    yd.setRequestMethod("POST");
    yd.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    yd.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "19004");
    yd.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "private");
    yd.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie", cookie);
    yd.setRequestProperty("X-AspNet-Version", "1.1.4322");
    yd.setRequestProperty("X-Powered-By", "ASP.NET");
    yd.setRequestProperty("Server", "Microsoft-IIS/6.0");
    yd.setDoOutput(true);
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(yd.getOutputStream());

    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    //out.write(data);
    out.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yd.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();

}
```

}

I think i figured out you can't read and write in the same connection, but won't you loose the cookie the server just sent? Any clarification would be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
yd.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "name=John;surname=Lennon;jsessionid=1234567890");
```

Comment: Im confused? what does that mean?

Comment: this is what you have to send to your server. Server can send to client header 'Set-Cookie'. Client can send to server header "Cookie". So I have just written and example for you. Obviously the value of cookie should be yours.

Comment: but the problem is I am not allowed to read and write with the same conection , so once I open a new connection it will be a different cookie right?

Comment: No. You are confused with the terminology. The cookie are valid during HTTP session that may exist minutes and hours and consist of many HTTP requests (GETs and POSTs). Client sends cookie using request header Cookie. Server may ask client to set cookie using response header Set-Cookie. Special cookie is session id. The name of this cookie is server specific. In java world jsessionid is a standard. But client does not have to know this. It sends ALL cookies that belong to current session including session id.